# Android search manager results not showing up in UIAutomator tree

Tags: android, ui-automation, android-uiautomator, appium

I am trying to figure out how to get to the elements shown in global search results in Android. All the other elements are showing up in the [UIAutomator](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html) tree. If you look at the below image, there is no notion of Seafood, Outdoor Seating etc.

Which means these elements aren't visible to accessibility tools as well. Is there something that we should be using so that these elements are visible in the UI tree.

Search I was talking is within the app  - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/SearchManager.html

[image: From UIAutoamtorview]

Answer (score 0):

It may depend on the hardware or OS version.  On a screen that looked like this:
[image]

I was able to find the result elements.  I did not use page_source to view the tree, so I'm not sure what it looked like - I was able to find by text.  If that doesn't work, I'm afraid you may be out of luck... hopefully I'm wrong.

Comment: I am talking about searching with in the app http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html. No its not hardware specific because the emulator I was using is 4.3

Comment: Oh, you said "global search results in Android" which sounds like the system global search.  You could try connecting with selendroid and doing a page_source().  It sometimes shows more info (including hidden things) than using the Android driver.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the appium inspector which shall provide you with the details of even hidden elements.
http://appium.io